# Can not set state by function is rendered by function in reactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jsx, dropdown, setstate

I'm trying to make a sidebar menu without lib and I got a problem.

I have a function used for setState, but it only works with `JSX` in `return`, when I render the menu and pass this function, it is run but `setState` not working in it.

Hear is my code:

```
export default function DropdownSideMenu(props) {
    const [state, setState] = useState({});

    const renderDropdownMenu = (data) => {
        return data.map((item) => {
            if (item.child.length >= 1) {
                return (
                    //THIS IS NOT WORKING, doSomeThing run but state not change.
                    <li key={item.id} onClick={() => doSomeThing(item.value)}>
                        <NavLink to={item.link}>{v[item.name]}</NavLink>
                        <ul>{renderDropdownMenu(item.child)}</ul>
                    </li>
                );
            }

            return (
                <li key={item.id}>
                    <NavLink to={item.link}>{v[item.name]}</NavLink>
                </li>
            );
        });
    };

    const doSomeThing = (value) => {
        console.log(value);
        setState(value);
    };

    return (
        <ul>
            {renderDropdownMenu(props.data)}

            {/* THIS IS WORKING, doSomeThing run well */}
            <li onClick={() => doSomeThing(value)}>
                <NavLink to="/">Test</NavLink>
            </li>
        </ul>
    );
}
```

UPDATE: Problem-solve
I found a big mistake in the project, when project building, I make a Layout component and PUT IT INTO CONTAINER COMPONENT, this is the wrong way because when we struggle Sidebar in Layout component Router will re-render the container and make Layout re-render so Sidebar can not make action setState.

I FIXED BY PUT LAYOUT INTO APP COMPONENT and WRAP ALL CONTAINER INSIDE LAYOUT COMPONENT, it works fine.

P/s: If someone see another mistake, please mention it in the comments. Thanks you so much.

Comment: Where is the value defined in onclick method? Do you want to pass event in callback? And How did you know the setState is not working, probably you are passing same value everytime

Comment: What is `props.data`? How are you verifying/validating that state isn't being updated? It doesn't appear that `state` is even used in your example snippet.

Comment: state is not being used, there is no v object  in renderdropdown, there is no variable declaration or value assigned to value passed to doSomeThing. There are many pieces missing.

Comment: @VivekKumar  i check console.log(state) before and after run setState in doSomething() so i sure (90%) it not run when we click item render by renderDropdownMenu

Comment: @DrewReese props.data is a fixed data like data = [ {name: "A", child: [{name: "C"} ] },  {name: "B", child: [] }]